# How can I change radius from drawable if direction changes?

Tags: android

How can I change radius because when choose Arabic language or any RTL language appear to me like image below

*Left To Right (It's good)*
[image]

*Right To Left (Not good)*

[image]

*Drawable File*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/MA0Settings" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="55dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="55dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Resources Framework to provide an alternate drawable file for RTL languages. See [Providing Alternative Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources) for details:

> The layout direction of your app. `ldrtl` means "layout-direction-right-to-left". `ldltr` means "layout-direction-left-to-right" and is the default implicit value.
>
> This can apply to any resource such as layouts, drawables, or values.

So you could have this file structure:

```
res/
    drawable/
        your_drawable.xml
    drawable-ldrtl/
        your_drawable.xml
```

And for the `ldrtl` drawable file, reverse the rounded corners:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/MA0Settings" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="55dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="55dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

With these two drawables in place, you don't need any special Java/Kotlin code to choose between them. The framework will do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with two drawable file 
and with check on language you can apply dynamically 
in your java file

first one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/MA0Settings" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="55dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="55dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

second one

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/MA0Settings" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="55dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="55dp" />
</shape>
```